# What is the correct way to catch model object deleted time in django?

Tags: django

**signal CODE :**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=TestModel)
def update_log(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    TestModelLog.objects.create(description=instance.description, datetime=instance.updated)


@receiver(post_delete, sender=TestModel)
def delete_log(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    TestModelLog.objects.create(description=instance.description, datetime=now())
```

**model CODE:**

```
class TestModel(models.Model):

    description = models.CharField(max_length=34)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I made signal code like above one and which is to catch log of `TestModel`.

As you can see, I can get update time using `instance` as `datetime=instance.updated`. And it is correctly the same as `TestModel`'s updated time.

When I want to get deleted time, `datetime=instance.updated` is not working.

So I tried to catch deleted time using `datetime=now()`.

But I'm curious about that there is other good way except `datetime=now()`.

Would you let me know other good way of catching object's deleted time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `TestModelLog` you may have something like:

```
class TestModelLog(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=34)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

So then creating the TestModelLog should be like:

```
TestModelLog.objects.create(description=instance.description)
```

as `auto_now_add` will do the magic.

Comment: Thanks dmitryro. I have a question. Why it's better than `instance.updated` or `now()`?

Comment: This way you don't have to specify, this will be done automatically for you at the time of `TestModelLog` object creation.